# How to deal with categorical feature in a Gaussian Mixture model clustering model

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am performing clustering by Gaussian Mixture model using EM algorithm in R. U use the `mclust` package. My data (205 observations and 25 variables) has both categorical and numerical variables. **How do I deal with that problem?**

My first thought is to transform my categorical variables to binary variables and then standardize the numerical variables in my data set. Is there any problem with that approach from a **theoretical point of view?**

Answer (score 2):

Gaussian distributions are *continuous distributions*.

There is no meaningful way to apply this famous "bell shaped curve" onto categorical data - binary encoding clearly does not make sense either. You have to find something else to use **instead of Gaussians**...

So instead of hacking to make your data fake Gaussian, you should rather make the algorithm match your data and problem.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what algorithms would be a better fit for handling continuous and categorical values?

Comment: The EM algorithm is fine, but you'll need to enhance it with a multinomial distribution, for example. That should be straightforward, just a little bit of math an a few lines of code afterwards.

Comment: Curious, could one not apply some factor analysis of mixed data to transform the data into a continuous space?